# Flutter: How to show data based on defined Container

Tags: flutter

I have a JSON like this ([API](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/tft-test-48c87.appspot.com/o/hexagon.json?alt=media&token=cf84ef93-0af1-4af3-b919-3aa0ff75ad54)):

```
[
  {
    "object": "A",
    "position": 2
  },
  {
    "object": "B",
    "position": 5
  },
  {
    "object": "C",
    "position": 9
  },
  {
    "object": "D",
    "position": 13
  }
]
```

**I want to set the position for each `Container` (from 1-14) so that when loading data, it will display `object` corresponding to each position.**
[image]

So pls help me, I'm new to code, if the answer is full code, that would be great, this is the main file:

```
import 'package:ask/model/hexagon_model.dart';
import 'package:ask/services/hexagon_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:polygon_clipper/polygon_clipper.dart';

class HexagonPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HexagonPageState createState() => _HexagonPageState();
}

class _HexagonPageState extends State<HexagonPage> {

  List<Hexagon> _hexagon = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    HexagonServices.getData().then((data) {
      setState(() {
        _hexagon = data;
      });
    });
  }

  get abc => 40.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hexagon'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey)))),
                    Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey)))),
                    Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey)))),
                    Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey)))),
                    Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey)))),
                    Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey)))),
                    Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey)))),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey)))),
                    Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey)))),
                    Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey)))),
                    Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey)))),
                    Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey)))),
                    Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey)))),
                    Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey)))),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please be more specific about what portion of code you need and what the end result should be, in the pictures 'current' seems to be the same with 'want'

Comment: @Develocode 777 Right below "current", I noted each position I wanted (from 1 -> 14), and with "want", I put the objects (A, B, C, D) in position (2,5,9,13) like the JSON file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you?

```
 
  List<Hexagon> _hexagon = [];
    
  List<int> positions = [];

  List<List> rows = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

        positions = List.generate(13, (index) => index+1);

    positions.forEach((element) {
      if((element-1)%7 == 0){
        rows.add([element]);
      } else {
        rows.last.add(element);
      }
    });

    HexagonServices.getData().then((data) {
      setState(() {
        _hexagon = data;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hexagon'),
      ),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: 
             rows.map((e){

               double i = e.first/7;
                double right, left;
              if(i.floor().isOdd){
                right = 20.0;
                left = 0;
              } else {
                right = 0;
                left = 20.0;
              }

             
               return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: right, left:left),
                child: Row(
                   children: e.map((e){

                      Widget child = Container();

                      _hexagon.forEach((element) {
                        if(element.position == e){
                          child = Text(element.object);
                        }
                      });

                    return Container(width: abc, child: ClipPolygon(sides: 6, child: Container(child: Center(child: child), decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey))));
                   }).toList(),
                 ),
               );

             }).toList()
            ,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have edited to reflect the new information you provided.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but it has an [error here](https://i.imgur.com/BEtQvXv.jpg)

Comment: you might need to sort the list first ```_hexagon.sort((a, b)=>a.position.compareTo(b.position));```. Also does the list contains only those 4 elements (A, B, C, D)? or 14 as it is in the picture?

Comment: It shows nothing, I tried adding the sort method but [nothing changed](https://i.imgur.com/x2XnaKi.jpg). Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: you didn't answer my question, does the list contains only those 4 elements (A, B, C, D)? or 14 as it is in the picture?

Comment: Ahh, sorry, the list contains only 4 elements (A, B, C, D) as JSON file, the other 14 numbers in the picture below are the position that I want to put for each hexagon, the screen will not show up numbers, the screen will only show element (A B C D ) according to the position of the hexagon.

Comment: I have edited to reflect the new information you provided.

Comment: Yeahh, It works! it's almost perfect except it's missing 1 hexagon [here](https://i.imgur.com/M9BMiH4.jpg) :D. BTW, in my real project, it will have 28 hexagons like [this](https://i.imgur.com/stH5YGO.jpg), please do me one more favor, update it to 28 hexagons :">

Comment: I changed `13`=> `14` in `positions = List.generate (14, (index) => index + 1);` then it seems perfect, thank you very much xD

Comment: try changing 14 to 28 ```positions = List.generate (28, (index) => index + 1);```, it should work

Comment: Yup, it worked great, that's all I wanted. You did help me a lot. Many thanks! xD